# Does every point of a differentiable have a unique tangent i.e does every point of a non-linear differentiabel function have different derivatives?

Tags: derivatives

I want to ask whether every point of a differentiable nonlinear function can have unique tangents with respect to its neighbouring points i.e every point of a differentiable function have different derivatives than its neighbouring points derivatives.

Comment: I guess $e^x$ is a basic example. Having different tangent at different point

Comment: What is the exact thing ,you want to ask

Comment: $f(x)=x^4\sin^2(1/x),f(0)=0$ the tangent at $x=0$ is the same as the tangent at $x=1/(n\pi)$

Comment: @parthsachdeva Thanks ,you pointed out a perfect example to work with.

Comment: @Anuj Actually even x^2 does have different tangents for different x

Comment: Now that you mention it ,the function with form x^a does have different tangents for different value of x